# anomaly detection in vehicle sensor data

Tags: bigdata, anomaly-detection, sensors

I am currently diving deeper into understanding more about anomaly detection in regards to vehicle's data generated by sensors.

It seems like there is no proper book or article that goes deeper into this topic.

Hoping to get help on where and how I could find anything regarding this topic. Maybe some of you had to deal with something like this and have acquired some knowledge on where to find some sources.

would really appreciate some help

Comment: What is special about vehicle sensor data ?  There are many (gazillions at a guess) books and papers on anomaly detection in sensor data, what features of vehicle sensors makes those resources unsuitable for you ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark Can you offer me any sources ?

Comment: Your favourite search engine is a better place to ask that question.

Answer (score 0):

Anomaly Detection in sensor data can be approached in many ways. A thorough introduction is available in these books:

- [Anomaly Detection Principles and Algorithms](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319675244) by Mehrotra et.al (2017)
- [Outlier Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319475776) by Aggarwal et.al (2017)

These cover the different approaches like distance-based, clustering-based et.c, along with time-series models as well as ensemble models.